# Change Prometheus Scrape Job Name

Tags: metrics, prometheus

We are using prometheus to scrape some metrics, but right now we want to change the job name. if i just change the name directly, it will not show the history chart in grafana(start with the new job name metrics) . Can we change the old metric's job name direct using some tools?

Now we are run the new and old metrics scrape in parallel for one month, and stop the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to retroactively change labels.